How to send context between multiple Mistral AI api call to keep conversation like a chat bot?
I want to create a chat bot like using Mistral AI api. But Api respond like a new start between each call and it does not keep the context. Here is my python code (from documentation):
import os
from mistralai import Mistral

api_key = "my api key"

client = Mistral(api_key=api_key)

chat_response = client.agents.complete(
    agent_id="my agent id",
    messages = [
        {
            "role": "user",
            "content": "Hello",
        },
    ]
)
print(chat_response.choices[0].message.content)

How to send context between each call?

Asking Mistrai Ai itself solved my issue !
I need to send all previous message with assistant role. here is a full working example that keep context:
import os
from mistralai import Mistral

api_key = "secret api key"

client = Mistral(api_key=api_key)

# Initialiser l'historique des messages
message_history = []

def get_chat_response(user_message):
    # Ajouter le message de l'utilisateur à l'historique
    message_history.append({"role": "user", "content": user_message})

    # Appeler l'API avec l'historique des messages
    chat_response = client.agents.complete(
        agent_id="my agent id",
        messages=message_history
    )

    # Ajouter la réponse de l'agent à l'historique
    agent_message = chat_response.choices[0].message.content
    message_history.append({"role": "assistant", "content": agent_message})

    return agent_message

while True :
    user_message = input(">: ")
    response = get_chat_response(user_message)
    print(response)


Please go through the GenAI Policy - GenAI should not be used to write answers on StackOverflow. Thanks!

As mentioned here:

The chat completion API accepts a list of chat messages as input and generates a response.

So, to maintain context between each call when using the Mistral AI API, you can manage the conversation history yourself by keeping track of the previous messages and sending them along with each new message to the API.
Here's a bare-bone example of implementing this:
.
.
.
conversation_history = []

conversation_history.append({
    "role": "user",
    "content": user_message,
})

chat_response = client.agents.complete(
    agent_id="my agent id",
    messages=conversation_history
)

response = chat_response.choices[0].message.content

conversation_history.append({
    "role": "assistant",
    "content": response,
})
.
.
.

